# Propiedad no hallada en java.lang.string

Tags: java, jsp

Buenas tardes, tengo una aplicación web y quiero devolver datos a un jsp, pero al momento de ingresar, no me muestra nada en pantalla (pantalla en blanco) y me sale el siguiente error:

```
    GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet jsp lanzó una excepción
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Propiedad 'FecPrestacion' no hallada en el tipo java.lang.String
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:229)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:206)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:317)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.jsp.menuAnestesista_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fformatDate_005f0(menuAnestesista_jsp.java:421)
    at org.apache.jsp.menuAnestesista_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(menuAnestesista_jsp.java:326)
    at org.apache.jsp.menuAnestesista_jsp._jspService(menuAnestesista_jsp.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at servlet.LoginUsr.cargaAnestesista(LoginUsr.java:128)
    at servlet.LoginUsr.doPost(LoginUsr.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /menuAnestesista.jsp en línea 88

85:                     <c:forEach items="${requestScope.listadoAnestesia}" var="anestesia">
86:                         <tr>
87:                             <td>${i}</td>
88:                             <td><fmt:formatDate type="date" value = "${anestesia.FecPrestacion}" /></td>
89:                             <td><c:out value="${anestesia.fecARA}" default="---"></c:out></td>
90:                             <td><c:out value="${anestesia.fecRendicion}" default="---"></c:out></td>
91:                             <td><c:out value="${anestesia.afiliado()}"></c:out></td>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at servlet.LoginUsr.cargaAnestesista(LoginUsr.java:128)
    at servlet.LoginUsr.doPost(LoginUsr.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Propiedad 'FecPrestacion' no hallada en el tipo java.lang.String
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:229)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:206)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:317)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.jsp.menuAnestesista_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fformatDate_005f0(menuAnestesista_jsp.java:421)
    at org.apache.jsp.menuAnestesista_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(menuAnestesista_jsp.java:326)
    at org.apache.jsp.menuAnestesista_jsp._jspService(menuAnestesista_jsp.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    ... 35 more
```

En definitiva me dice esto:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Propiedad 'FecPrestacion' no hallada en el tipo java.lang.String.
```

Gracias

Edito asi no lo complico mas de lo que esta

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.listadoAnestesia}" var="anestesia">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${i}</td>
                        <td><fmt:formatDate type="date" value = "${anestesia.FecPrestacion}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.fecARA}" default="---"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.fecRendicion}" default="---"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.afiliado()}"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.nroAfiliado()}"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.osocial()}"></c:out></td>
```

El error me lo da en la primera opcion que recupero del request

Esta es mi clase, es un modelo del cual vuelco la data que necesito mostrar asi no me complico tanto en los JSP, estos datos son agregados en el servlet que devuelve los datos.

```
package entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class ModeloAnestesia implements Serializable{

    /* 
     * VARIABLES
     * ----------
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idAnestesia, nroAfiliado, nroVias, nroTalon;
    private String afiliado, edad, usuario, medico, anestesista, sanatorio, osocial, tpoAnestesia;
    private Date fecPrestacion, fecARA, fecCarga, fecRendicion;
    private boolean nocturno, feriado, fds;

    /*
     * CONSTRUCTORES
     * -------------
     */
    public ModeloAnestesia() {}

    public ModeloAnestesia(int idAnestesia, Date fp, Date fa, Date fc, Date fr, String afiliado, int nroAfiliado,
            boolean nocturno, boolean feriado, boolean fds, int nroVias, String edad, String usuario, String medico,
            String anestesista, String sanatorio, String OS, String tpoAnestesia, int nroTalon){
        this.idAnestesia = idAnestesia;
        this.fecPrestacion = fp;
        this.fecARA = fa;
        this.fecCarga = fc;
        this.fecRendicion = fr;
        this.afiliado = afiliado;
        this.nroAfiliado = nroAfiliado;
        this.nocturno = nocturno;
        this.feriado = feriado;
        this.fds = fds;
        this.nroVias = nroVias;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.medico = medico;
        this.anestesista = anestesista;
        this.sanatorio = sanatorio;
        this.osocial = OS;
        this.tpoAnestesia = tpoAnestesia;
        this.nroTalon = nroTalon;
    }

    /*
     * METODOS
     * -------
    */
    public int getIdAnestesia() {
        return idAnestesia;
    }

    public void setIdAnestesia(int idAnestesia) {
        this.idAnestesia = idAnestesia;
    }

    public int getNroAfiliado() {
        return nroAfiliado;
    }

    public void setNroAfiliado(int nroAfiliado) {
        this.nroAfiliado = nroAfiliado;
    }

    public int getNroVias() {
        return nroVias;
    }

    public void setNroVias(int nroVias) {
        this.nroVias = nroVias;
    }

    public String getAfiliado() {
        return afiliado;
    }

    public void setAfiliado(String afiliado) {
        this.afiliado = afiliado;
    }

    public String getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getMedico() {
        return medico;
    }

    public void setMedico(String medico) {
        this.medico = medico;
    }

    public String getAnestesista() {
        return anestesista;
    }

    public void setAnestesista(String anestesista) {
        this.anestesista = anestesista;
    }

    public String getSanatorio() {
        return sanatorio;
    }

    public void setSanatorio(String sanatorio) {
        this.sanatorio = sanatorio;
    }

    public String getOsocial() {
        return osocial;
    }

    public void setOsocial(String osocial) {
        this.osocial = osocial;
    }

    public String getTpoAnestesia() {
        return tpoAnestesia;
    }

    public void setTpoAnestesia(String tpoAnestesia) {
        this.tpoAnestesia = tpoAnestesia;
    }

    public Date getFecPrestacion() {
        return fecPrestacion;
    }

    public void setFecPrestacion(Date fecPrestacion) {
        this.fecPrestacion = fecPrestacion;
    }

    public Date getFecARA() {
        return fecARA;
    }

    public void setFecARA(Date fecARA) {
        this.fecARA = fecARA;
    }

    public Date getFecCarga() {
        return fecCarga;
    }

    public void setFecCarga(Date fecCarga) {
        this.fecCarga = fecCarga;
    }

    public Date getFecRendicion() {
        return fecRendicion;
    }

    public void setFecRendicion(Date fecRendicion) {
        this.fecRendicion = fecRendicion;
    }

    public boolean isNocturno() {
        return nocturno;
    }

    public void setNocturno(boolean nocturno) {
        this.nocturno = nocturno;
    }

    public boolean isFeriado() {
        return feriado;
    }

    public void setFeriado(boolean feriado) {
        this.feriado = feriado;
    }

    public boolean isFds() {
        return fds;
    }

    public void setFds(boolean fds) {
        this.fds = fds;
    }

    public int getNroTalon(){
        return nroTalon;
    }

    public void setNroTalon(int nroTalon){
        this.nroTalon = nroTalon;
    }

}
```

Agrego la parte del servlet que me recupera los datos.

```
// Metodo que instancia los listados que necesito mostrar al principio y me deriva a la pagina correspondiente
    private void cargaAnestesista(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        try {
            anestesias = cargarDatos(user);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            request.setAttribute("anestesias", anestesias);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("menuAnestesista.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }


    private ArrayList<ModeloAnestesia> cargarDatos(Usuario u){
        //Instancio las variables que declare arriba
        ctrlAnestesia = new CtrlAnestesia();
        anestesista = new Anestesista();
        ctrlAnestesista = new CtrlAnestesista();
        ArrayList<Anestesia> listado = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ModeloAnestesia> modelos = new ArrayList<>();

        //Primero recupero los datos del anestesista
        anestesista = ctrlAnestesista.buscarAnestesista(u.getUser());//tengo que ver si lo voy a necesitar??

        /* Recupero los datos que voy a mostrar:
         * - Obra Social
         * - Medico
         * - Sanatorio
         * - TpoAnestesia
         * El resto de los valores los paso de la anestesia directamente
         */
        //Recupero las anestesias del anestesista activo.
        try {
            for(Anestesia a: ctrlAnestesia.listarAnestesia())
            {
                if(a.getUser() == u.getUser()){
                    listado.add(a);
                }
            }
        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Recorro el listado de anestesias recuperados

        if(!listado.isEmpty()){
            for(Anestesia l:listado){
                modelos.add(cargaModelo(l));
            }
        }
        return modelos;
    }

    //Cargo la instancia del modelo que corresponde a la anestesia activa en el for de arriba
    private ModeloAnestesia cargaModelo(Anestesia l){
        modelo2 = new ModeloAnestesia();
        modelo2.setIdAnestesia(l.getIdAnestesia());
        modelo2.setFecPrestacion(l.getFecPrestacion());
        modelo2.setFecARA(l.getFecAra());
        modelo2.setFecRendicion(l.getFecRendicion());
        modelo2.setAfiliado(l.getAfiliado());
        modelo2.setNroAfiliado(l.getNroAfiliado());
        modelo2.setOsocial(cargaOS(l.getIdOS()));//Ejecuto el metodo para devolver el dato
        modelo2.setNocturno(cambiaTipo(l.getNocturno()));
        modelo2.setFeriado(cambiaTipo(l.getFeriado()));
        modelo2.setFds(cambiaTipo(l.getFds()));
        modelo2.setNroVias(l.getNroVias());
        modelo2.setEdad(l.getEdad());
        modelo2.setNroTalon(l.getNroTalon());
        modelo2.setMedico(cargaMedico(l.getIdMedico()));
        modelo2.setSanatorio(cargaSanatorio(l.getIdSanatorio()));
        modelo2.setTpoAnestesia(cargaTpoAnestesia(l.getIdTpoAnestesia()));
        modelo2.setUsuario(l.getUser());
        return modelo2;

    }
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código?

Comment: Ahi ya edite Danniel, gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Podrías mostrar además la clase anestesia

Comment: Disculpen chicos, soy nuevo y tengo la costumbre de explicar poco y lo poco que explico creo que es entendible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te está indicando es que `anestesia` es de tipo **String**, tipo que no tiene ninguna propiedad ni método "`FecPrestacion`".

Esto al parecer está ocurriendo porque tu `listadoAnestesia` no contiene una colección de tu modelo `ModeloAnestesia` sino de elementos `string`; el código que debes compartirnos es cómo generas esa lista.

---

**EDIT**

Adicionalmente, viendo tu modelo resulta que no tienes ninguna propiedad `FecPrestacion` sino una variable privada llamada `fecPrestacion` (con minúscula al principio, notación Camell). Esto es que, además de no existir esa propiedad, la que sí existe es privada por lo que nunca podrás acceder a ella desde fuera.

Prueba a cambiar el código en la vista de manera que llames a los `getters` de tus propiedades, así:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.listadoAnestesia}" var="anestesia">
    <tr>
        <td>${i}</td>
        <td><fmt:formatDate type="date" value = "${anestesia.getFecPrestacion()}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.getFecARA()}" default="---"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.getFecRendicion()}" default="---"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.getAfiliado()}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.getNroAfiliado()}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.getOsocial()}"></c:out></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

De acuerdo con [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24630701/5360283), lo único que debes hacer es eliminar el «`requestScope`» en la etiqueta para el forEach (e ignorar mi *edit* anterior):

```
<c:forEach items="${listadoAnestesia}" var="anestesia">
    <tr>
        <td>${i}</td>
        <td><fmt:formatDate type="date" value = "${anestesia.fecPrestacion}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.fecARA}" default="---"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.fecRendicion}" default="---"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.afiliado}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.nroAfiliado}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${anestesia.osocial}"></c:out></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**pero** considera también que el *atributo* que estás definiendo en `cargaAnestesista` es "anestesias" y en el jsp iteras sobre "listadoAnestesia", [debes usar el mismo nombre de atributo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579172/how-to-obtain-request-session-servletcontext-attribute-in-jsp-using-el).

Comment: Hola Kroneaux, gracias por la ayuda, lo de la primer letra mayuscula, fue una prueba que quedo. Hice lo que me dijiste y me tira el siguiente error: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Unable to find method [getFecPrestacion] with [0] parameters. Con lo cual no funciona.

Comment: Compártenos el código donde generas la lista, ya que aunque hagas correcciones en la vista, si la lista sigue siendo simplemente de `String`s nada va a funcionar.

Comment: Ahí ya agregue la parte en donde genero la lista.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, espero que te ayude.

Comment: Gracias Kroneaux, entre otros errores de lógica, me ayudo mucho tu ayuda. Te hago una consulta relacionado. El listarAnestesias era una variable que se definía arriba del jsp. Es lo mismo que este o no este el set? Y como paso los datos sino tengo el scope. Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda